# Security policies and procedures

Tags: security-testing, security

I am compiling a list of general security policies and procedures at the moment. 
The following items have been included:

- Acceptable use - this policy defines what behaviors are acceptable and what behaviors are not.
- Internet access - this policy defines whether someone can access internet or not.
- Data classification - this policy defines how open (or secret) data should be.
- Password policy - this policy indicates how password should be chosen.

Can you think of more security policies?

Comment: You may have better luck on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: as all your points are about policy not software.  You may wish to delete here and move to there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs more on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OK. I will try posting my question there. Thanks @MichaelDurrant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you think of more security policies?

1. Minimum access, this policy limits access to a need to know basis.
2. Network access, this policy limits who can access a network.
3. VPN access (remote access), this policy limits who can access a network via VPN remotely.
4. User account management, this policy decides who can create, delete accounts.
5. Configuration and Change Management, this policy decides who can modify configurations.
6. Server security, this policy indicates how a server should be managed.
7. Mobile devices, this policy shows how laptops, smartphones are managed as they are easily stolen.
8. Guest access, how a guest can access information
9. Meltdown procedure, when security is breached, what should we do?

There are more policies out there. Above are all I can think of.